# How often does China influence Hollywood market by allowing or rejecting a film?

Tags: production, film-industry, box-office

Can china convince Hollywood to change blockbuster movie scripts by allowing or not allowing movies into the Chinese market?

If they can, how regularly/consciously do they use this power?

Comment: I think you're referencing the latest controversy over Marvel's choice to use an Irish actress to play an originally Tibetian character in the 2016 movie *Doctor Strange*. While this is not an actual policy as far as I know, it makes sense due to economic concerns; China is one of the biggest markets for Hollywood movies, so it would make sense for Hollywood to try and meet China's concerns. See http://www.salon.com/2016/09/25/hollywoods-new-china-syndrome-the-countrys-enormous-audience-means-money-for-movie-studios-and-some-restrictions/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. China, a huge market, has the legal and economic clout to force changes to a movie's regional release *if they want to release it there*. Some changes are done preemptively by the production, while others are done after the fact. China also bans some topics outright such as time travel.

This is no different than changes the MPAA requires for a certain rating or any other location or zoning based law. If Hollywood wants to avoid those changes, their option is to not release in China. But the economic "loss" is a pretty damning incentive to make the changes. They are no way ***obligated*** To release in China, aside from greed.

Comment: I'm intrigued! Why do they ban time travel?

Comment: Because "disrespect of history". Also, if the Chinese peasant starts thinking that you can change the way things are, the government is at risk of revolt.

Comment: Time travel used to be a way to get past censors, as you can make allegories, and sometimes criticize the government that way 

Sci-Fi in general seems like a very political genre by definition.